# ui-bootstrap date picker and validation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I set up a date picker as shown below. If I put in an invalid date, I always see the "Availability Date is required" message instead of the "Enter a valid date" message. Anyone see what is wrong here?

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid && productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty}">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputAvailabilityDate">Availability</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="date" 
                id="inputAvailabilityDate" 
                name="inputAvailabilityDate" 
                class="form-control" 
                data-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                ng-model="vm.product.releaseDate" 
                data-is-open="vm.opened" 
                data-show-weeks="false" 
                required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-click="vm.open($event)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid && productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty">
        <span ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error.required">
            Availability Date is required
        </span>
        <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="!productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error.required">
            Enter a valid date.
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can see 1 problem. required is not validating input. It just checks if there is a value, not which value. You could also write `ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$valid` and you should get the same behavior. The other problem I see is that if you realy use twittet-bootstrap, then your model do not know that the value has changed. You should use ui-bootstrap instead, so the framework component would update the model for you. required will never change by using plain JavaScript.

Comment: Ok I were wrong :-), but my answer show you what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in this little plnkr example, that you can [not show "Enter a valid date"](http://plnkr.co/edit/wk60K6yIaZQ95yuHP3Dm?p=preview), because your expression is not valid!

There must be `productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid && productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty && !productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error.required` == true to show the Message. But if there is a invalid date the model is set to undefined! Thats because datepicker do not set the date if the date is invalid.

Here you can see a example [how the "Enter a valid date" message will show](http://plnkr.co/edit/BwwqGrQY6NKeDhl6MDrg?p=preview).

Code-behind:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.vm = {
    product: {
      releaseDate: new Date()
    }
  };

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

HTML-Code:

```
<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form name="productForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <span class="input-group">
      <input type="date" id="inputAvailabilityDate" name="inputAvailabilityDate" 
      class="form-control" data-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
      ng-model="vm.product.releaseDate" data-is-open="opened" 
      data-show-weeks="false" required />

          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
      </button>

      </span>

            </span>
          </div>
          <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid && 
    productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty">
                <span ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error.required">
                    Availability Date is required
                </span>
          <span class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid && 
    productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty">
                    Enter a valid date.
                </span>
          </span>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        vm: {{vm|json}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        productForm: {{productForm|json}}
        <br>productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$valid: {{productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$valid}}
        <br>productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error: {{productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$error|json}}
        <br>productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty: {{productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$dirty}}
        <br>productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid: {{productForm.inputAvailabilityDate.$invalid}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```